# Realmファイルを複数に分けてリレーションを組むことができるか

Tags: realm

Realmファイルを複数に分けてリレーションを組むことができるでしょうか
A.realm　Aテーブル
B.realm　Bテーブル
があって、AとBテーブルで親子関係で定義できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

できません。あるファイルに保存されているRealmオブジェクトを別のファイルに保存することはできないためです。リレーションを持たせる場合は同じファイルに保存されている必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり無理ですか。
親情報は変わらないので、子の情報だけrealmファイルをダウンロードして
成立しないかなと思っていたのですが。ちなみに子のテーブル部分だけをcsv等で
importすることは可能ですか？